# MVC View in iFrame

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, iframe, master-pages

**Disclaimer to iFrame haters:** *I have a reason for doing this.*

I am trying to load a `View` into an `iFrame`, and have it automatically refresh every so often.

On my `Index` page, I am loading an `iFrame` and calling an `Action` like so:

```
<iframe id="content" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="@Url.Action("Page", "Home")"></iframe>
```

In my code, I have     :

```
public ActionResult Message()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And on said page (still referring to the iFrame) I have :
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="19">` with some additional content.

My thought behind was to *only refresh the iFrame* - however it's refreshing the entire page.
When I inspect the render, I see the `iFrame` was never loaded:

[image]

What will be the best way to achieve what I want?

**Edit for clarity:** The HTML in the picture is of the *entire document*. Everything betweent the `<div id="pagewrap" />` tag should be in the iFrame

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the iframe this way

```
<iframe name="ifr"></iframe>
@Html.ActionLink("MyAction", "MyController", null, new { target = "ifr" })
```

and setting to null your "iframed" view layout

```
@{
  Layout=null;
}
```